# Using Wordcounts to check whether a pre-recorded wordcount matches article found online

Tags: python, text, dictionary, counter

I have a database from 2010 of URL's for news articles and their corresponding wordcounts. I need to check whether the 2010 URL still has the article.

I can successfully check wether the URL is valid, scrape the URL for all HTML, and then apply a filter to get only visible text (which is more than the article).

I am currently using the subtract function in collections.Counter to then compare wordcounts between the recorded wordcount and the newly scraped visible text. However, I don't have access to the code that made the original wordcount in 2010, so some counts are always different (*both* higher and lower) even when the article is present/matching.

Is there a better way to compare a pre-recorded wordcount (dict) to a string of filtered HTML (article) to see whether they *roughly* match?

I can provide code if it helps. One example URL is:
http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/11/world/asia/11gates.html

** Edit ** I'm using Python 3.4.1. I'd prefer to stay in that, but I also work a lot in Matlab and R, so those are options as well.

Comment: What kind of language/resources you have access?

Comment: Response added to first post -- thanks for pointing out my omission! I'm doing everything in Python 3.4.1... but can switch to Matlab or R if there's a good reason to.

Comment: For making a webpage simpler you could go with BeautifulSoup http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/.  A long time ago I've used like this http://ericonotes.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/farewell-google-reader.html?m=1